# Show mysql data with getting column name dynamically

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to getting a column name and the value dynamically and show it using bootstrap collapase.

My code gets data correctly but can't show properly with collapse.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach ($row as $col => $value) {
        $replace=rtrim($col, '0123456789');
        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            foreach($row2 as $key => $value2) {
                print'<div class="panel-group" id="#panel-364465">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <a class="panel-title collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#panel-364465" href="#'.$col.'">'.str_replace('_', ' ', $replace).'</a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="'.$col.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">'.$value2.'</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand further if it is possible or not. If it is possible, how?

Comment: still using mysql! use mysqli cause mysql is going to expire!